# how to get customer last visited date in magento2?

Tags: magento2

I want to find inactive customer list that is customers who are inactive from a certain amount of time I have an account creation date of the customer if I get last visited date then I can put logic to get inactive customers.

Answer (score 1):

Magento saves customer `last visited date` at `customer_visitor` table at the database.
This table is related to the collection class `Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Visitor\Collection`.

At, `customer_visitor`  table's `last_visit_at` column save customer last visited time.

So, you want to get a collection of the customer which is not visited at the system, then used below:

```
<?php

namespace StackExchange\Magento\Test;


class InActiveCustomer {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface
     */
    private $_localeDate;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Visitor\CollectionFactory
     */
    private $visitorCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Visitor\CollectionFactory $visitorCollectinFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $_localeDate    
    ) {

        $this->visitorCollectionFactory = $visitorCollectinFactory;
        $this->_localeDate = $_localeDate;
    }
    public function getInActiveCustomer()
    {

        $from = strtotime('-7 day', strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:i:s")));

        $visitorCollection = $this->visitorCollectionFactory->create();
        $visitorCollection->addFieldToSelect('*'); // Select all field
        $visitorCollection->addFieldToFilter('customer', ['gteq' => 1 ]);
        // Filter the Collection by 7 Old
        $visitorCollection
                ->addFieldToFilter('last_visit_at', $this->_localeDate->date($from, null, false)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    }
}
```

**Note the code is not tested. Given base on the idea. In this sample, i have trying to get a collection of 7day old customer.**

Also, note that Magento clear  this table record automatically depends on the setting

Comment: after changing the customer to customer_id, It's working for me. Thank you for your valuable reply.

Answer (score 0):

Hi,

You can get the customer visitor data through this model.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerVisitorModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Visitor')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', array('neq'=> ''));
```

Note: Don't use objectmanager. Get the model data through block or helper.

Let me know if you have any queries.

Thanks

Comment: but your answer is using objectManager

Comment: You can create the block to use this code. I tested this code in phtml file directly for you.