Where is the file with all customers details (last log-in date)
Where is the folder that contains the information of registered customers?
I need to extract the 'last login date" with e-mail/name/id
Thanks!

Check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/270267/21339

thanks but i'm not a dev. I'm looking for file like csv,xml to manage by myself and get infos that i need.

AFAIK there is no such functionality available by default, For said functionality you need a custom module

The closest listing of what do you want is inside the Admin > Customers > Customers now online.
In that list you can filter by Type = "Customer" and you will have it's last time on the system. It has names and email as you requested.
To allow every customer, you might need to use a very old date on the Last activity > from filter to catch all the data.

If you have a database access, you can use this query :
select entity_id, firstname, lastname, email, last_login_at from customer_entity as ce
left join customer_log as cl on cl.customer_id = ce.entity_id
order by last_login_at DESC

